# Cart total doesn't update after adding an item to the cart (using API) using Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v1, xmlrpc

I'm using Magento 1.9 CE and am using XML RPC to connect to [Magento's API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.totals.html) and after I add an item to the cart, the "totals" do not update.

Here's the order of operation:

1. [`login`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html) to api
2. [`cart.create`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.create.html) - create an empty cart
3. [`cart_customer.set`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartCustomer/cart_customer.set.html) - set a "guest" user
4. [`cart_customer.addresses`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartCustomer/cart_customer.addresses.html) - set "guest" user address
5. [`cart_product.add`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html) - add a product to the cart
6. **At this point we have a cart with 1 item** in it. I can then verify that the cart looks ok with [`cart_product.list`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.list.html) which returns the following:

   ```
    [
     [
      {"product_id":"10",
      "sku":"159996",
      "name":"Redwood Turtle",
      "set":"9",
      "type":"simple",
      "category_ids":["2","7"],
      "website_ids":["1"]}
     ]
    ]
   ```
7. [cart.totals](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.totals.html) - Now ***when I try to get the totals for the cart, it is null/empty***! Here's what I get back:

   ```
    [
      [
        {"title":"Subtotal",
         "amount":null},
        {"title":"Grand Total",
         "amount":null}
      ]
    ]
   ```

**What method do I call to populate the totals for the cart?**

Comment: IIRC the Mage_Sales_Model_Quote needs to collect collectTotals() and save() after that - I don't have access to code at this very right moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough, if you call **`cart_customer.addresses` after calling `cart_product.add`**, then the **`totals` get updated**! Here's how I did it using XML-RPC in javascript:

**Note**: *This code sample assumes that you already have already logged into the Magento API* and stored the session number plus cart number to session storage (I used https://github.com/julien-maurel/js-storage to do this)

```
addToCart(10,1,function(){
    setCartCustomerAddresses(function(){
        getCartTotals(function(totals){
            console.log("Cart Totals = ",totals);
        });
    });
});

function addToCart(productId,qty,callback)
{
    var products = {"product_id":productId,"qty":qty};
    var cartNum = storage.get('cart');
    var session = storage.get('session');

    $.xmlrpc({
        url: 'https://example.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
        methodName: 'call',
        params: [session, 'cart_product.add',[cartNum,[products]]],
        success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log("cart_product.add. Successfully added "+productId+" to the cart.");
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            callback(error);
        }
    });
}

function setCartCustomerAddresses(callback)
{
    var cartNum = storage.get('cart');
    var session = storage.get('session');

    var customerShipping = {"mode":"shipping",
    "firstname":"Guest",
    "lastname":"Guest",
    "company":"test",
    "street":"123 maple",
    "city":"Anaheim",
    "region":"12",
    "postcode":"92806",
    "country_id":"US",
    "telephone":"0123456789",
    'is_default_shipping':0,
    'is_default_billing':0};

    var customerBilling = {"mode":"billing",
    "firstname":"Guest",
    "lastname":"Guest",
    "company":"test",
    "street":"123 maple",
    "city":"Anaheim",
    "region":"12",
    "postcode":"92806",
    "country_id":"US",
    "telephone":"0123456789",
    'is_default_shipping':0,
    'is_default_billing':0};

    custAddresses = [customerShipping,customerBilling];

    $.xmlrpc({
        url: 'https://example.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
        methodName: 'call',
        params: [session, 'cart_customer.addresses',[cartNum,custAddresses]],
        success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
                console.log("success ",response);
                callback(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log("error ",error); 
                callback(error);
        }
    });
}

function getCartTotals(callback)
{
    var cartNum = storage.get('cart');
    var session = storage.get('session');

    $.xmlrpc({
        url: 'https://example.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
        methodName: 'call',
        params: [session, 'cart.totals',[cartNum]],
        success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log("success ",response);
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            callback(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Code Sample Above requires:

- [JQuery](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWsMzUuvzRAhXGWpAKHXJHBa8QFghCMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjquery.com%2Fdownload%2F&usg=AFQjCNGwtoLJyWLN_jrbuSStsXYv7X_nMg&sig2=EX7M8Wd4xXI8QjqO6i60Tw)
- [JQuery Storage](https://github.com/julien-maurel/js-storage) (You can use whatever you want to keep the session # and cart # though)
- [JQuery XML-RPC](http://jquery-xml-rpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) to call Magento's API.
- You'll also need to **login** before trying the code above, then **create a cart**.

Another Note: Be careful when loggin into the API via Javascript. It is NOT SECURE! Anyone can view the code and get your username and password!! Therefore, **I highly recommend that you create a NEW API user** in the Magento backend that only has access to listing products, retrieving info, etc. Make sure the user cannot do anything terrible to your site because it is public.