# Magento 1.9 soap API : Totals and subtotals always equal 0 after adding products to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, soap-api-v1

I am facing an issue when adding product to a created cart, the product is added to the cart successfully so as the customer, but when I retrieve the cart info total shows always 0, here is steps that I have followed : 
1. login to api
2. create an empty cart
3. set a "customer" user
4. add product to cart 
5. add addresses to cart

Here is my  code

```
 // login info here 
$shoppingCartIncrementId = $proxy->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create' );

echo 'cart id '. $shoppingCartIncrementId;


// cart_customer.set - set a "customer" user

$customerAsGuest = array(
    "customer_id" => 327,
    "mode" => "customer"
);

$resultCustomerSet = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart_customer.set', array( $shoppingCartIncrementId, $customerAsGuest) );

echo '<br>resultCustomerSet : '.$resultCustomerSet;


 // **************************** cart_product.add****************************


    $arrProducts = array(
        array(
            "sku" => "003",
            "quantity" => 1,
             "options" => array(         
                "subscription_type" => 8,
                "subscription_start" => "30/11/2018",
                "qty" => 1
             ) 
        )
    );

    $resultCartProductAdd = $proxy->call($sessionId,"cart_product.add", array($shoppingCartIncrementId, $arrProducts));

    echo 'ProductAdd : '. $resultCartProductAdd;



// ______________________________________cart_customer.addresses_______________________________

$arrAddresses = array(
    array(
    "mode" => "shipping",
    "firstname" => "testFirstname",
    "lastname" => "testLastname",
    "company" => "testCompany",
    "street" => "testStreet",
    "city" => "testCity",
    "region" => "testRegion",
    "postcode" => "testPostcode",
    "country_id" => "MA",
    "telephone" => "0123456789",
    "fax" => "0123456789",
    "is_default_shipping" => 0,
    "is_default_billing" => 0
),
array(
    "mode" => "billing",
    "firstname" => "testFirstname",
    "lastname" => "testLastname",
    "company" => "testCompany",
    "street" => "testStreet",
    "city" => "testCity",
    "region" => "testRegion",
    "postcode" => "testPostcode",
    "country_id" => "MA",
    "telephone" => "0123456789",
    "fax" => "0123456789",
    "is_default_shipping" => 0,
    "is_default_billing" => 0
)
);

$resultCustomerAddresses = $proxy->call($sessionId,     "cart_customer.addresses",array($shoppingCartIncrementId,$arrAddresses));
echo '<br> adresse result : '. $resultCustomerAddresses;




  // **************************** infos cart ****************************
 $result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart.info',$shoppingCartIncrementId);

 var_dump($result);
```

I have found this post but it did resolve my issue: [Cart total doesn't update after adding an item to the cart (using API) using Magento 1.9 CE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/cart-total-doesnt-update-after-adding-an-item-to-the-cart-using-api-using-mag)

Here is the response that I get (info cart):

```
["store_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2018-11-27 13:59:41" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2018-11-27 13:59:44" ["converted_at"]=> NULL ["is_active"]=> string(1) "0" ["is_virtual"]=> string(1) "0" ["is_multi_shipping"]=> string(1) "0" ["items_count"]=> string(1) "1" ["items_qty"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["orig_order_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["store_to_base_rate"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["store_to_quote_rate"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["base_currency_code"]=> string(3) "MAD" ["store_currency_code"]=> string(3) "MAD" ["quote_currency_code"]=> string(3) "MAD" ["grand_total"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["base_grand_total"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["checkout_method"]=> string(8) "customer" ["customer_id"]=> string(3) "327" ["customer_tax_class_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["customer_group_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["customer_email"]=> string(13) "projet@test.ma" ["customer_prefix"]=> NULL ["customer_firstname"]=> string(11) "projet test" ["customer_middlename"]=> NULL ["customer_lastname"]=> string(11) "projet test" ["customer_suffix"]=> NULL ["customer_dob"]=> NULL ["customer_note"]=> NULL ["customer_note_notify"]=> string(1) "1" ["customer_is_guest"]=> string(1) "0" ["remote_ip"]=> NULL ["applied_rule_ids"]=> NULL ["reserved_order_id"]=> NULL ["password_hash"]=> NULL ["coupon_code"]=> NULL ["global_currency_code"]=> string(3) "MAD" ["base_to_global_rate"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["base_to_quote_rate"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["customer_taxvat"]=> NULL ["customer_gender"]=> NULL ["subtotal"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["base_subtotal"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["subtotal_with_discount"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["base_subtotal_with_discount"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["is_changed"]=> string(1) "1" ["trigger_recollect"]=> string(1) "0
```

here is the info about magento : 
magento version : 1.9 
Soap api : version 1